# How to calculate gear tooth position while assembling a planet gear?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears

A stepped planet series gear looks like this:

[image]

Given that:

- Planet gears are evenly distributed (with 120°)
- Sun-gear-1 and Sun-gear-2 is lined up.
- Sun gear tooth counts: nS1, nS2
- Planet gear tooth counts: nFGS (first gear step), nSGS (second gear step)
- Ring gear tooth count: nR1
- Ring gear belongs to Sun-gear-1 and FGS
- One tooth of FGS and one tooth of SGS is lined up (on the same line to the center) and marked with `M`.
- FGS of Planet-gear-1 is touching the Ring at `M`th tooth.

In order to assemble this gearbox:

- Make `M` point of first-gear-step of Planet-gear-1 touch the Ring at `Ring-tooth-0`.
- Make `M` point of first-gear-step of Planet-gear-2 touch the Ring at `Ring-tooth-x`.
- Make `M` point of first-gear-step of Planet-gear-3 touch the Ring at `Ring-tooth-y`.
- Roll the Planet-gear-2 to `R1/3`th tooth of the Ring.
- Roll the Planet-gear-3 to `R1*2/3`th tooth of the Ring.

In this procedure, how do we calculate `x` and `y` values?

## Example Case

> Taken from http://tricolour.net/rohloff.html

> I realized I needed to turn each index tooth by 2/3 of a tooth to get it to mesh.

[image]

Index tooth (`M` point) of the gears are marked with a black dot in the picture.

Comment: Maybe something is being lost in translation, but shouldn't x and y just be R1/3 and 2*R1/3 since the planets are equally spaced?

Comment: @jko No. I added the example case, please see my edit.